# Django how to link Users to Usermodel

Tags: django, model, profile

Hello I am pretty new to Django and don't get yet fundamental ideas of Users.
I was able to create a registration page to create users which are shown on the admin page in the "Authentication and AUthorization -> Users".

Now I want the users to logg in and create their profiles. They should add some additional information like name, bio, picture etc.
Every user should be able to add and see its own profile.

To do that I created a model:

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        bio = models.TextField()
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
        def __str__(self):
            return self.firstname + ' | ' + self.lastname
```

In my view and the html I am able to add these informations to the model.
But HOW exactly can I relate this "Profile"-Model to the individual user? What do I miss here?

Comment: From the documentation: [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/) and [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via adding a `OneToOneField` relationship between `Profile` and the default `User`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' | ' + self.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `OneToOneField` to the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL). This settings contains a string with the qualified name of the user model. This is better than linking to the `User` model of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, because if you later create a custom user model, the references to that user model will be updated:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

For more information, see the [*referencing the user model* section of the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks. worked so far. Just one more question. 
In the admin section in the profiles I will get an dropdown menu to select the user. 
Is there a way to automate it? The name, email etc worked. but the username not.